# Как правильно передать JSON из PHP в JS

Tags: javascript, php, json, foreach

Помогите пожалуйста, кто хорошо знает веб с такой проблемой.
Есть JS код, который добавляет на карту метки. Данные меток в JSON формате. Вывожу данные в переменную JS из PHP - выдает ошибку JS кода "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined". При этом если эту же переменную отправляю в console.log, затем копирую из консоли данные вручную и подставляю в JS код, то все объекты нормально выводятся на карте.
JS код:

```
    $.post('fullMap.php', {
        location: location,
        address: address,
        phone: phone,
        sor: sor,
        type: type,
        category: category,
        rooms: rooms,
        date1: date1,
        date2: date2,
        price1: price1,
        price2: price2,
        area1: area1,
        area2: area2,
        postfix: postfix,
        notfirstfloor: notfirstfloor,
        notlastfloor: notlastfloor,
        notanswer: notanswer,
        answer: answer,
        favorite: favorite,
        blacklist: blacklist,
        sold: sold,
        isagent: isagent
    }).done(function(data) {
        setMarker(data);            
    });
function setMarker(geojson) {
  console.log(geojson);
    // add markers to map
  geojson.features.forEach(function (marker) {
    // create a HTML element for each feature
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';

    // make a marker for each feature and add it to the map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
      .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
      .setPopup(
        new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
          .setHTML(
            '<h3>' +
              marker.properties.title +
              '</h3><p>' +
              marker.properties.description +
              '</p>'
          )
      )
      .addTo(map);
  });   
}
```

И соответственно вот пример JSON из консоли, который при ручной вставке отлично работает:

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection','features': [{'type': 'Feature','geometry': {'type': 'Point','coordinates': [36.162632, 51.72834]},'properties': {'title': 'Комната 14 м² в 2-к., 3/9 эт.','description': 'Курская область, Курск, ул. Чернышевского, 17'}},{'type': 'Feature','geometry': {'type': 'Point','coordinates': [35.352839, 52.339242]},'properties': {'title': 'Аренда офисных и торговых помещений от 18 м² и выш','description': 'Курская область, Железногорск, ул. Гагарина, 28'}},]}
```

Как его правильно передать из PHP в переменную?

Comment: В переменную скорее всего записывается строка, сделайте ```geojson = JSON.Parse(geojson);```.

Comment: Не помню в какой версии стандарта (вроде это так называется) js, есть возможность не дублировать ключ: значение, если они одинаково названы. То есть можно просто ```{location, address}``` и в таком духе.

Comment: на стороне пхп выставите заголовки content-type для json. это будет более корректный путь, чем json.parse

Comment: JSON.Parse(geojson) разберет JSON. А мне надо в формате JSON данные передать

Comment: формат JSON  это сериализация в текстовую строку, вот вы и передатее его текстовой строкой и получаете ее в JS коде. Если хотите получить из нее данные, то надо эту строку десериализовать. Поскольку автоматически это не происходит, вам предлагют десериализацию вручную. Не происходит это, вероятно, потому что вы не выставляете заголовки `content-type: application/json` при отправке ответа. Так что передаете ли вы данные в формате json - да. Разбираются ли они на клиенте автоматом - нет.

Comment: Как и где я могу установить content-type: application/json?

Comment: вы этот вопрос дольше писали, чем гуглили бы.

Comment: Переписал $.post на $.ajax c dataType: 'json' и contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", но через success: function(data) в переменной data, которую смотрю через console.log(data) теперь просто пустая строка как бы я не пытался отправить ее из PHP. Пробовал echo $marker, echo json_decode($marker), return json_decode($marker). Пробовал даже просто строчку отправить текстовую типо echo json_decode('олололо') - все равно в console.log(data) только пустая строка. Уже всю голову сломал, помогите пожалуйста(((